# Sqlite delete error

Tags: java, sqlite

Im using a very simple delete Query "DELETE FROM S WHERE SNO="+row;

though when running i get the error no column S1 exists when entering that i want to delete S1?

And i am 100% sure that i have S1 in the database.

the error:

java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: S1)

my delete method:

```
public void Delete() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    String query = "";
    //asks the user for a tablename.
 String tablename = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Which table do you want to delete from?");
 String row = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Which row do you want to delete?");

 // checks if the input is equal to any of these names and changes the query thereafter.
        switch (tablename) {
            case "S":
                query = "DELETE FROM S WHERE SNO="+row;
                break;
            case "J":
                query = "DELETE FROM J WHERE JNO ="+row;
                break;
            case "P":
                query = "DELETE FROM P WHERE PNO ="+row;
                break;
            case "SPJ":
                query = "DELETE FROM SPJ WHERE SNO ="+row;
                break;
                 case "s":
                query = "DELETE FROM S WHERE SNO ="+row;
                break;
            case "j":
                query = "DELETE FROM J WHERE JNO ="+row;
                break;
            case "p":
                query = "DELETE FROM P WHERE PNO ="+row;
                break;
            case "spj":
                query = "DELETE FROM SPJ WHERE SNO ="+row;
                break;
        }
Connection c = null;
Statement stmt = null;
try {
  Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
  c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
  c.setAutoCommit(false);
  System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

  stmt = c.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

  rs.close();
  stmt.close();
  c.close();

} catch ( Exception e ) {
  System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );

}
System.out.println("You have deleted from " + tablename + " where rowID = " + row);
}
```

Comment: What type is `row` in your DB?  Is it `VARCHAR` or `INT`?

Comment: In all the listed `sql quries` I don't see any `s1` as columnname or table name. Moreover you are doing same operations for `Capital case` and `Lower case`. you can merge them together like `case"j": case "J":// do something... break;`

Comment: So what you entered was, exactly, `S1`?

Comment: It's Text. And yeah the columnname is SNO and SNO is the only unique identifier which has S1,S2,S3,S4 etc..

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, strings are delimited with quotes:

```
query = "DELETE FROM x WHERE xNO = '" + row + "'";
```

Without the quotes, words are interpreted as table or column names.

Anyway, to avoid formatting problems (when strings contain quotes) and to avoid SQL injection attacks, it is a better idea to use parameters:

```
query = "DELETE FROM x WHERE xNO = ?";
...
PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1, row);
rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: nvm got it working. though i get no errors now but it still doesn't delete? :/